# How do I Make a FTB Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I wanna play FTB with my friend and I has downloaded the FTB Monster Modpack Server from the FTB website. Do both me and my friend need to have Forge and the Monster Modpack mods in the .minecraft\mods folder to make the mods work on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You both need to be using the [FTB launcher](http://www.feed-the-beast.com/) as far as I know. You might be able to use forge but I've always done it through FTB. Make sure you both have the same version client that the server is running on. If you have any difficulty connecting, try using [evolve](http://www.evolvehq.com) (my personal favorite) or [hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx). Port forwarding is also recommended but I prefer using it as a last resort since it can be a pain in the butt at times.

Comment: The portforwarding is not a problem, cause I had a vanilla server before.